# How to close a while loop for an ArrayList that is collecting user input

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist, while-loop

The question sounds simple enough but I have spent 2 hours looking for the answer and I can't seem to find it. I am trying to make a program that populates an array list with user input (of integers) and then closing it when the number 0 is typed.

So far I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.*;
/**
 * Write a description of class ArrayList2 here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */

public class Numbers

{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println ("Enter a list of integers (Enter 0 when done): ");

        ArrayList<Integer> fullArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        while (keyboard.hasNextInt())
        {
            fullArray.add(keyboard.nextInt());
            System.out.println (fullArray);


        }

        System.out.println (fullArray);
    }
}
```

My issue isn't getting the user input, but closing the arraylist when 0 is typed. I know that `hasNextInt` returns `true` as long as their's another `int` but 0 is also an `int` so it will not close the arraylist. I have tried simply saying `if(keyboard.nextInt == 0)`, but that breaks my code and only adds every other number to my arraylist. If anyone can help me it would be much appreciated. thanks.

Comment: You need to put the contents of keyboard.nextInt() into a variable, then check the value of that variable and if it's 0 you call "break;" otherwise you put the value of the variable in your array and continue as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a new `nextInt()` which will make you skip every other value, simply store the `nextInt` you already used into a variable (in this case `nextValue`), check to see if it is `0`, `break` from the loop if it is, otherwise you add it to the `List`.

Here is the working version below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println ("Enter a list of integers (Enter 0 when done): ");
    ArrayList<Integer> fullArray = new ArrayList<>();

    while (keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
        int nextValue = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (nextValue == 0) {
            break;
        }
        fullArray.add(nextValue);
        System.out.println (fullArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, had to move the fullArray.add(nextValue); into the while loop because it couldn't find the local variable, but otherwise my program now works. :D

Comment: @Lioti Hmm it should already be in the `while` loop in the code I wrote?  Glad it worked for you though!